# Laravel: Unable to use route which is not inside group prefix in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I just created a  group of routes with prefix `"cms"` and create some routes inside it and all are working fine but now when i am trying to use that route in my anchor tag which one is not inside the group its showing route not found

Code:

```
Route::get('page/{slug}',   ['as'=>'view.pages' , 'uses'=>'PagesController@pageView' ]);
Route::group(['prefix'=>'cms','namespace' => 'cms'],function(){
    Route::get('testing', function(){
                    echo "<a href='".route('view.pages','test')."'>Click</a>";
                });
 });
```

its working fine i just place the route inside group but its showing error when route not inside the group, its showing:

```
Route [view.pages] not defined.
```

can anyone tell me whats the problem ?

Comment: Can you add the code where you call the route ?

Comment: you can check the testing route in my code

Comment: Ok try it like this `route('view.pages', ['slug' => 'test'])` in the testing route !!

Comment: no, same error..

Comment: test it directly from the browser `localhost/page/test` what you get ?

Comment: its accessible directly from browser

Comment: So i think the problem is just in the call of `route` method inside Routes file !! to test that create a testing view that contains simply `<a href="{!! route('view.pages', ['slug' => 'test']) !!}">Click</a>` return it in the testing route `return view('test');` and click the link to test if it'sworking so it's just the call as i said :)

Comment: i just give here example of testing route,actually i am using it in my view page but still not able to access..

Comment: And its working fie when i just paste that route inside the group.. even in route file also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156458/discussion-between-maraboc-and-rahul-sharma).

Comment: Have you checked namespace ? Your page/{slug} url come under namespace 'cms' or not ?